# Consulta sobre como sumar las ventas de la semana vigente

Tags: sql, sum

necesito hacer un sum de las ventas de la semana actual. El problema es que no puedo sumar valores que no pasaron, me trae null. Hay alguna manera de resolverlo?¿
Lo que hice es:

```
DECLARE @hoy datetime
SET @hoy        =       GETDATE()

SELECT  @Hoy                                                                Hoy,
        DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)   Lunes,
        DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)   Domingo 


Select          @TotalVentaDia = SUM (monto_neto) 
From            ventas
Where           FECHA >= DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy) AND
                FECHA  <= DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrán ayudar por favor.
Gracias

Comment: Si no hay ventas ¿Qué esperas que te arroje?

Comment: EN qué base de datos es esto?

Answer (score -1):

Hay una función que si tenes un null devuelve el valor que vos indiques, por ejemplo:

```
COALESCE(null, 0)
```

devuelve 0

En tu caso queda:

```
DECLARE @hoy datetime
SET @hoy        =       GETDATE()

SELECT  @Hoy                                                                Hoy,
        DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)   Lunes,
        DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)   Domingo 


Select          @TotalVentaDia = COALESCE(SUM (monto_neto),0)
From            ventas
Where           FECHA >= DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy) AND
                FECHA  <= DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @Hoy)) % 7, @Hoy)
```

Que entiendo es lo que estás buscando